# Why is remoter not working when I enable encryption?

Tags: r, libsodium

I'm trying to connect to a [remoter](https://github.com/RBigData/remoter) server and getting the following error:

```
Error in sodium::auth_decrypt(encrypted, getkey(private), getkey(theirs)) : 
  is.raw(nonce) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In unserialize(rmsg) :
  cannot unserialize ALTVEC object of class 'wrap_raw' from package 'base'; returning length zero vector
```

If I run the server with `secure = FALSE` everything works as expected. This is the dockerfile that i'm using to run the server:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    libsodium-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    r-cran-tidyverse \
    r-cran-remotes \
    r-cran-rstan \
    r-cran-rstanarm \
    r-cran-rstan \
    && install.r \
    remoter \
    sodium \
    drat \
    RcppArmadillo \
    RcppEigen \
    StanHeaders \
    aws.signature \
    aws.s3

COPY R/Makevars /root/.R/Makevars

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
VOLUME [ "/root/.ssh" ]

CMD ["R", "-e", "remoter::server(port = 49152, secure = T, password=Sys.getenv('api_key'))"]
```

Is this a bug in the remoter package or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which R version is being installed? In fact, knowing which versions of all the packages that are being installed would be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm using R 3.6 and the latest version of the packages available on cran. It looks like this might be a bug in sodium https://github.com/RBigData/remoter/issues/53